# Items.Restrict returns duplicate items

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

When using Items.Restrict I noticed that it returns a set of items containing every item multiple times:

```
MAPIFolder sentFolder = _nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
DateTime sentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).Date;
var filter = $"[SentOn] >= '{sentDate:d}'";
Console.WriteLine($"Filter {filter}");
Items items = sentFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
foreach (MailItem mailItem in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"'{mailItem.Subject}'/{mailItem.SentOn}");
}
```

Output is e.g.:

```
Filter [SentOn] >= '28.04.2020'
'Test-Mail'/11.05.2020 10:09:05
'Test-Mail'/11.05.2020 10:09:05
... repeat about 10 times ...
```

The code above is called from a WPF application in a separate Thread.

I wrote a console application which does exactly the same:

```
var application = new Application();
var ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
var filter = "[SentOn] >= '28.04.2020'";
Console.WriteLine($"Filter " + filter);
Items items = folder.Items.Restrict(filter);
foreach (MailItem item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"'{item.Subject}'/{item.SentOn}");
}
```

Output is (executed on the same machine):

```
Filter [SentOn] >= '28.04.2020'
'Test-Mail'/11.05.2020 10:09:05
'Test-Mail 2'/11.05.2020 11:05:34
```

What am I missing? Why does the code mentioned first return duplicate results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code above is called from a WPF application in a separate Thread.

Outlook uses a single-threaded apartment model. All your calls should be marshalled to the main thread by Outlook even if you try to use it. So, you should never use the Outlook object model on secondary threads. Instead, you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is built on - Extended MAPI which allows running multithreaded applications. Or just use any third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption.